# Display form data before final submission (confirmation view)

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to give user a chance to see what he entered and verify it before data get submitted. When user click on submit form I want to display all data entered in form into separate page.  When user clicks verify on that page then data go back to controller that finally submits the data.

I think the main problem is that how to move all form data from one page to another page.

Comment: What is your specific question? What have you tried?

Comment: Store it in a database/session/cookie for retrieval later. Which you use will depend on how long you need to retain the data and what level of security you need.

Comment: The title of this post is pretty terrible.  "How to solve this" doesn't tell us much of anything.  Please specify what exactly the subject of your question is.

Comment: I've changed title and removed some words from the question as it sounds useful by itself. I.e. pretty much every commerce site shows "please verify your credit card information" view before final "spend all your money" click.

Comment: My, question to you is no need to go to the server? Perhaps for some extra validation? Now, if you don't need to go server this can be achieved by client side with some JavaScript before you actually submit the data. Lemme know if this would work for you. I can post some code

Comment: @coffeeyesplease thanks your idea really help me and i did it by jquery . Thankyou Very Much

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to create a new controller action, e.g., "VerifySubmission". Submitting your form should post to YourController.VerifiySubmission(). The View for VerifySubmission displays the data so the user can review it, and also writes out the fields as hidden form fields. There is a submit button on this "verify" page, when the user clicks it, it POST's the hidden form fields to your final "FormSubmit" controller action (whatever you have named it), where it gets saved to the database.

EDIT: Also, please update the title of your question so it gives some indication of what question you are asking.

Comment: Curious about this myself, is there an easy or automatic way to write all the values as hidden fields? If the viewmodel were serializable, I suppose you could serialize the entire thing as a hidden field in the "Verify" view, but I've never tried this. Wondering if there's a better, and standard way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to have the form posted to the controller.  For example, if you are using the `Index` page for the submission, your controller code would look something like this

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Verify(FormCollection form)
{
    ViewBag.FormItems = form;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Accept(FormCollection form)
{
    // Do whatever you need to do to store the data
    return View();
}
```

Now, if your users are submitting information that is in a model, you'll want to actually use that model in place of `FormCollection`, and set your `View`s to be strongly typed against that model (it'll be much easier to handle doing it as strongly typed model).

Admittedly, setting the `ViewBag` to just store the `FormCollection` is a lazy way of doing things, but in the absence of knowing what you really want to do, it works.  As I said, using a model for the input data would simplify things and make it more robust.

Answer (score 0):

One more approach to transfer data between enter data-confirm-final submit pages is to use [TempData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx) that allows you to save state (usually in SessionState) between 2 requests.