# ASP.NET MVC3 - displaying "updated" model values for summary display before form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view named `AddEditModule` that is used, believe it or not, for Adding or Editing a module. The workflow is kind of a wizard using navigation buttons that hide/show div's.

I've got a ViewModel called `AddEditModuleModel` (say that 10 times fast). In steps 1 & 2 I'm displaying my fields using various EditorFor's. In step 3, I'd like to use DisplayFor's to display a Summary of the **current values** of my textboxes (what's been updated in the View, not what was passed in in the model).

In my Silverlight days, I'd simply have two-way binding between my `'Step1.FirstName'` TextBox and a ViewModel property. In my Summary, I could simply display a TextBlock that was also bound to my ViewModel property, or I could use Element Binding to bind my TextBlock.Text proeprty to my Step1.FirstName.Text property.

I know I can't do that in MVC3, but I'm not sure how to solve this. I thought about just ajax posting the updated module and returning a new partial view called `ModuleSummary`, or something similar, but that seemed kinda hacky (and not entirely sure if that would mess up my file upload on the page).

Is there something I'm missing?

**[Edit - sample code]**

Scenario: 
I'm editing a model which originally has a title of "My Module". Obviously on initial load, my DisplayFor model.title is going to be set to "My Module". Let's assume, on step 1, I change the title to "My New Module Title". What I'd like to know is if there's a way to "refresh" my model when I click the button to display Summary to display my new title.

```
@model CEAcademy.AddEditModuleModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddModule", "Module", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(false)
<fieldset>
    <legend></legend>  
    <div id="step1">
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="summary">
        <div class="display-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title)
        </div>
        <div class="display-field">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.title)
        </div>            
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="showSummary" value="Step 2: View Summary" />
</fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone just asked a similar question 
[Display form data before final submission (confirmation view)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194434/display-form-data-before-final-submission-confirmation-view)
I'll ask you the same thing I asked that person. Do you need to go to the server? Is there some extra validation you need to do before displaying the summary?
If not, then you can "easily" do this client side. Use javascript (jQuery or some other lib) to display the summary and at the end then POST the data.

Comment: Use plenty of jQuery, so this won't be a problem. I know MVVM (silverlight) operates client side in RAM, but I suppose, now that I think about it, my viewmodel in MVC never finds its way to the client as an actual object, so I have nothing to update. Thx for the feedback